# Hover/click mismatch on fixed side button on my webapp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed red button which shows some info on click.On hovering the button,  a small info shows up.Click and hover both are working  on a same button.I have 2 problem scenario doing this thing -

1. **Problem 1 -** When I mouse hover on the red button DummyText div comes up and hides in 2-3 second ,that is working fine as I want .But when I remove the mouse from button i.e mouse out the DummyText hides quickly but I want it to hide out in 2-3 seconds only.
2. **Problem 2-** When I click the red button the divs on right open up, Now I want hover event to stop working in all cases.

   Below is the code of what I have tried. Hope Someone has a better solution on this.

Thanks in Advance!

```js
$('.FilIcon').click(function() {
  $('.ConservativeLikelyBox').toggle(100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hoverLikely').toggleClass('showMeNot');
  }, 100);

});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $(".ConservativeLikely");
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.ConservativeLikelyBox').hide(100);
    $('.hoverLikely').removeClass('showMeNot');

  }
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none
}

.ConservativeLikely {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 30%;
}

.FilIcon {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.DefineScopeForBC .ActButtonNew1 span {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid rgb(15, 170, 255);
}

.ConservativeLikely img {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox {
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(15, 170, 255);
  float: left;
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li.active a {
  color: rgb(15, 170, 255);
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li:hover a {
  color: rgb(15, 170, 255);
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li:first-child a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(15, 170, 255)
}

.hoverLikely {
  position: absolute;
  right: 42px;
  top: 47px;
  width: auto;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ConservativeLikely:hover>.hoverLikely {
  animation-name: ShowHideNew;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.ConservativeLikely:hover>.hoverLikely.showMeNot {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes ShowHideNew {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ShowHideNew {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes ShowHideNew {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ConservativeLikely">
  <span class="hoverLikely">DummyText</span>
  <div class="FilIcon"><img src="../../../images/cons_lik.png" width="30" /></div>

  <div class="ConservativeLikelyBox">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#"> Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) use mouseout function

Comment: @santosh gore what to do with mouseout function?

Comment: 2) $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave') call this function when you click on red button.it will disable hover effect.

Comment: can you make a working example from my code provided above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1 can be solved with just CSS. Here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbkx8r64/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="box show-pop-up">
  <div class="pop-up">this is popup</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.pop-up {
  outline: 1px solid yellow;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 10px;

  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s step-end;
}

.show-pop-up:hover > .pop-up {
  transition-duration: 0s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The basic idea is to have nonzero `transition-duration` on our pop up element and set `transition-duration` to `0s` on hover, so the pop up shows up immediately. But when we remove the mouse, the 'original' duration kicks in so the pop up stays for the animation duration. And since [transition-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) is specified as `step-end`, the pop up opacity goes from 1 to 0 at the end of animation.

Now the problem 2 is trivial. Since we can just toggle the `show-pop-up` class with javascript.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Adam K. `transition-delay` can be added, which enables us to add pop up fading animation. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbkx8r64/2/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbkx8r64/2/ - transition delay is better IMO than transition animation curve (for this case)

Comment: Yep, it makes it more customisable. Thanks, @AdamK!

Comment: Ideas for Problem 2?

Comment: @SahilDhir you want to not show pop up, whenever the 'menu' is open, right?

Comment: Yes..
When I close the red button the hover starts if my mouse is on the button.. which i dont want .It should work when I again put my mouse back.. Any idea or case how to achieve that?

Comment: I suppose you can remove `show-pop-up` class on click and add it back only when menu completely closes.

Comment: With [animation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Using_animation_events) you can listen to `animationend` on your menu element and add `show-pop-up` class then.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle on that because I did tried something similar but it dint worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Transition and transition delay can be used

```
.elem{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;
  transition-delay:1s;
}

.elem:hover{     
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0, visibility 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
```

This makes exiting hover delayed.

---

```js
$('.FilIcon').click(function() {
  $('.ConservativeLikelyBox').toggle(100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hoverLikely').toggleClass('showMeNot');
  }, 100);

});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $(".ConservativeLikely");
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.ConservativeLikelyBox').hide(100);
    $('.hoverLikely').removeClass('showMeNot');

  }
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none
}

.ConservativeLikely {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 30%;
}

.FilIcon {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.DefineScopeForBC .ActButtonNew1 span {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid rgb(15, 170, 255);
}

.ConservativeLikely img {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox {
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(15, 170, 255);
  float: left;
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li.active a {
  color: rgb(15, 170, 255);
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li:hover a {
  color: rgb(15, 170, 255);
}

.ConservativeLikelyBox li:first-child a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(15, 170, 255)
}

.hoverLikely {
  position: absolute;
  right: 42px;
  top: 47px;
  width: auto;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;
  transition-delay:1s;
}

.ConservativeLikely:hover>.hoverLikely {
  animation: hide 1s forwards;
  animation-delay:1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
 
  transition: opacity 0s;
  transition-delay: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.ConservativeLikely:hover>.hoverLikely.showMeNot {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes hide {
  0% {opacity:1;visibility: visible;}
  100% {opacity:0;visibility: hidden;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ConservativeLikely">
  <span class="hoverLikely">DummyText</span>
  <div class="FilIcon"><img src="../../../images/cons_lik.png" width="30" /></div>

  <div class="ConservativeLikelyBox">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#"> Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem 2 is not present if i understand its nature correctly.

Comment: Problem 1 solved correctly .Thumbs up for that :) . Problem 2 still exist.. When I close the red button the hover starts if my mouse is on the button.. which i dont want .It should  work when I again put my mouse back.. Any idea or case how to achieve that?